# Suppressing system calls when using gcc/g++

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

I have a portal in my university LAN where people can upload code to programming puzzles in C/C++. I would like to make the portal secure so that people cannot make system calls via their submitted code. There might be several workarounds but I'd like to know if I could do it simply by setting some clever gcc flags. libc by default seems to include `<unistd.h>`, which appears to be the basic file where system calls are declared. Is there a way I could tell gcc/g++ to 'ignore' this file at compile time so that none of the functions declared in unistd.h can be accessed?

Comment: What about using something like http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/systrace/ ?

Comment: I'm currently doing something just like systrace - just wondered if it was easier to bypass something which is so clearly differentiated (in man oages description at least) from regular library code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some particular reason why `chroot("/var/jail/empty"); setuid(65534);` isn't good enough (assuming 65534 has sensible limits)?

Comment: Is that something like creating/simulating a different user for running uploaded code? I've seen others use that approach - always wondered how.

Comment: The idea it to link with -static, write the binary to the jail, and run it. There's nothing else in the jail so they can't do much at all.

Comment: Ah! Thats a nice hack! Its like your own little sandbox! I think that would be a lot simpler than suppressing the system calls as is. Now, I've gone from sandbox idea to sandbox implementation. Thanks!

Comment: One stupid little thing, you still have to make sure they can't open network connections. Easy way: patch socket() system call to if (uid == some value) return -EPERM.

Answer (score 3):

Restricting access to the header file won't prevent you from accessing `libc` functions: they're still available if you link against `libc` - you just won't have the prototypes (and macros) to hand; but you can replicate them yourself.

And not linking against `libc` won't help either: system calls could be made directly via inline assembler (or even tricks involving jumping into data).

I don't think this is a good approach in general.  Running the uploaded code in a completely self-contained virtual sandbox (via QEMU or something like that, perhaps) would probably be a better way to go.

Comment: Thats true - hadn't thought of that. I guess sandboxing would be the way to go, just seems like a lot of overhead for such a simple (usually non-malicious) environment

Answer (score 2):

`-D` can overwrite individual function names. For example:

```
gcc file.c -Dchown -Dchdir
```

Or you can set the include guard yourself:

```
gcc file.c -D_UNISTD_H
```

However their effects can be easily reverted with `#undef`s by intelligent submitters :)

Comment: I see what you mean -  I think as Matthew Slattery pointed out, the way to go is to have some kind of a sandbox environment